# Springboot, Micrometer and Aws Lambda function

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-cloudwatch, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I'm trying to send metrics to AWS cloudwatch by using micrometer, however, I'm facing a problem with the AWS credentials.

```
ERROR i.m.c.CloudWatchMeterRegistry - error sending metric data. 
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: 
[com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@b23c49d: Failed to connect to service endpoint: , com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@7edf67de: profile file cannot be null]
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:136)r 
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1257)r   
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:833)r 
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:783)r    
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)r 
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)r  
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)r   
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)r  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)r  
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)r  at com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchClient.doInvoke(AmazonCloudWatchClient.java:2587)r 
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchClient.invoke(AmazonCloudWatchClient.java:2554)r   
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchClient.invoke(AmazonCloudWatchClient.java:2543)r   
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchClient.executePutMetricData(AmazonCloudWatchClient.java:2297)r 
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient$27.call(AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient.java:1215)r    
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient$27.call(AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient.java:1209)r    
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)r   
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)r at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)r    
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)r
```

The AmazonHttpClient is trying to retrieve the credentials using either the `EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper` or `ProfileCredentialsProvider`, but in the lambda environment the credentials are available through an execution role and also we have specific environment variables called `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.

So, is there any ways to tell micrometer to use a different AwsCredentials provider, for example `EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider`?

Comment: can't you create a `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` file that provides that `CredentialProvider`?

Comment: How are you creating the `CloudWatchMeterRegistry`? Custom `CloudWatchAsyncClient` should be passed into that, which can then use any credential provider you want.

Comment: @DejanPeretin I'm not creating on my own, it's provided as a bean in `CloudWatchExportAutoConfiguration`.  Can you post an answer with the necessary to create a custom CloudWatchMeterRegistry?

Comment: @DejanPeretin after creating my custom CloudWatchMeterRegistry bean, everything started to work.  I tried that yesterday but didn't work because  Terraform was not updating the code of my lambda function. Anyway, it's working now, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I was able to send the metrics by creating a custom `CloudWatchMeterRegistry` bean as follow:

```java
@Bean
@Primary
public CloudWatchMeterRegistry customCloudWatchMeterRegistry(
        CloudWatchConfig config, Clock clock, AwsRegionProperties awsRegionProperties) {

    AmazonCloudWatchAsync amazonCloudWatchAsync = AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient
            .asyncBuilder()
            .withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider())
            .withRegion(awsRegionProperties.getStatic())
            .build();

    return new CloudWatchMeterRegistry(config, clock, amazonCloudWatchAsync);
}
```

As you can see, now I can configure a custom Credentials Provider, in my case the `EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider`.

*Important hint:* The name of the bean shouldn't be `cloudWatchMeterRegistry` because this class `org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.metrics.CloudWatchExportAutoConfiguration` already has a declared bean with that name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a `Configuration` file to change the `Bean` for that?

```
@Configuration
public class ManualAWSCredentialProviderConfiguration {
  @Value("${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}")
  protected String accessKey;

  @Value("${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}")
  protected String secretKey;

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public AWSCredentialsProvider buildAWSCredentialsProviderManually() {
    return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
      new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, same problem.

Comment: @ele try to log the credentials that spring is assigning to those strings

Comment: The problem is that Micrometer is still using the EC2 and Profile credentials providers within the Cloudwatch client.

Answer (score 0):

When you add `aws-java-sdk-sts` to your dependencies (and thous having it on your classpath) will result in an extended provider chain. Then the execution role should get used.

For maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.52</version>
</dependency>
```

For gradle:

```
implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-sts', version: '1.12.52'
```